# How to use the same path prefix for resources (css and images) for development and production environment?

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am linking to resources such as **css or image** files in the application made with UI5 but I am facing a problem.

Usually, the path are for example:

```js
return "css/style1.css"; // for a stylesheet inside the folder css
return "img/image.jpg"; // for a image inside the folder img
```

And **once the application deployed it works fine** but when **running with SAP Web IDE both are not found** resulting in the 404-error.

So for running in SAP Web IDE, showing the style and image the path is:

```js
return "../../../../../webapp/css/style1.css"; #for a stylesheet inside folder css
return "../../../../../webapp/img/image.jpg"; #for a image inside folder img
```

And that is **working running with SAP Web IDE** but **it's not clean**. And I'm not sure either if it can work once it's deployed.

Is it a possible configuration or trick to be able to use standard link and run the app with SAP Web IDE for seing the result before to deploy?

Comment: When I had a similar problem, I solved it with [sap.ui.require.toUrl()](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui%23methods/sap.ui.require.toUrl).

Comment: According to the doc sap.ui.namespace is deprecated since version 1.1, I would prefer to use a not deprecated way if there is such a possibility

Comment: Yes, `sap.ui.namespace` is deprecated, but not `sap.ui.require.toUrl()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution to create a model for this:
In model.js:

```js
createImageRoot: function() {
  var oModel = new JSONModel({
    path: sap.ui.require.toUrl("the.namespace") // available since 1.58. Otherwise, use jQuery.sap.getModulePath instead.
  });
  oModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
  return oModel;
},
```

In Component.js, add in the init method

```js
this.setModel(models.createImageRoot(), "imageRoot");
```

And then for example :

```js
return this.getView().getModel("imageRoot").getProperty("/path") + "img/image.jpg"
```